TypeError when trying to import OrbitControls. What do I do?
I get this error when trying to import the OrbitControls
JS:
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene.add(cube);

camera.position.set(0, 20, 100);
camera.position.z = 5;

renderer.render(scene, camera);

controls.update();

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    controls.update();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}


HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="module" src="task9.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

I've tried to use different imports;
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
and
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.128.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
None of them work

Try this approach.
BTW your code has couple issues…

Don’t duplicate camera settings.
Initialise OrbitControls after renderer.
Add some lights to scene.
Remove unnecessary controls.update();
Call animation loop.

That version works fine:
import * as THREE from "https://esm.sh/three";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://esm.sh/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enabled = true;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

Look at these topics as well:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/cant-find-threejs-and-threejs-min-js-file/65270/3
Three.js breaks when trying to import OrbitControls.js

import OrbitControls from '../three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
Try this it may solve your problem.

The error you get says that the path to OrbitControls has to be absolute and not relative. Here are the differences. In a nutshell - you just have to replace the path to OrbitControls with './three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls' or '/home/&USER/path/to/OrbitControls'.

When I change the import to that, I get a new error:
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
